# LINQ or SQL queries. What is more efficient?

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq

I have a program with a database with information about people that contains  million records.

> One of the tasks were to filter the results by birth date, then group
>   them by city and finally compare the population of each city with the
>   given numbers.

*I started to write everything in SQL query, but then I started to wonder, that it may make server too busy and maybe it's better to do some calculations with the application itself.*

I would like to know if there are any rules/recommendations

- when to use server to make calculations ?
- when to use tools like LINQ in the application ?

Comment: Loading all into your app may cost a lot of memory. And loading all into your app also occupies your server.

Comment: @juergend: It is however also common to do some processing in the database and some processing in the rest of your program, for instance filter the data down in the database end and then do some complex transform to it in code.

Comment: This specific case doesn't sound terribly complicated. I'd try writing it in SQL first and see how it performs and what the query plan looks like.

Comment: @Matti Virkkunen: For example, i have two tables - cities and information about people. The task is to find in which city is the biggest population of people who are 40-50yo. In server I grouped results by date, filtered by age and then returned list to the application, where I compared results. Another example - I have to find how many teenagers(14-18yo) were living in each city. In this case I made all the processing in the server and returned the completed list to the program leaving the program only to display results. Am I thinking the right way?

Comment: I think the 40-50 thing could be solved in one query with a simple JOIN and GROUP BY. If you post your table schemas maybe somebody can even post you an example.

Comment: for your requirement, it is best to do it in sql query and return the result to your application. Just think of it, transferring millions of data from Server to client will be expensive. What you need is only the summarize information, and SQL Server can perform the GROUP BY and aggregate efficiently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For such requirements, there's no fixed rule or strategy, it is driven by application / business requirements, couple of suggestions that may help:

- Normally Sql Query does a good job in churning lots of data to deliver a        smaller result set post filtering / Grouping / Sorting. However it needs
   correct table design, indexing to optimize. As the data size increase Sql may under perform
- Transferring data over the network, from hosted database to application is what kills the performance, since network can be big bottleneck, especially if the data is beyond certain size
- In memory processing using Linq2Objects can be very fast for repetitive calls, which needs to apply filters, sort data and do some more processing
- If the UI is a rich client, then you can afford to bring lots of data in the memory and keep working on it using Linq, it can be part of in memory data structures, if the UI is Web then you need to Cache the data
- For having the same operations as sql, for in memory data, for multiple types, you need  custom code, which preferably use Expression trees along with linq, else a simple linq would do for a known fixed type

I have a similar design in one of my web application, normally it is a combination, which works best in the most of the practical scenarios